# OTP not sent in Firebase Authentication app using both email and contact number verification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am making an app in Android Studio in which a user has to verify both his contact number and email address before uploading his details in Firebase Realtime Database. I am verifying the email address first and then moving on to contact number verification. The email address verification is working just fine but the contact number verification  is not. This is the code I am using for contact number verification :

```
public class OtpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView otpAppear;
    TextInputLayout contactVer;
    CountryCodePicker ccpVer;
    Button otpGet;
    String mVerificationId;
    PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken;
    //PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_otp);

        contactVer=findViewById(R.id.verifyContact);
        otpAppear=findViewById(R.id.appearOtp);
        otpGet=findViewById(R.id.getOtp);
        ccpVer=findViewById(R.id.ccpVerify);

        ccpVer.registerCarrierNumberEditText(contactVer.getEditText());


        /*otpGet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String verCont=ccpVer.getFullNumberWithPlus();

                PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(verCont,120, TimeUnit.SECONDS,OtpActivity.this,mCallbacks,forceResendingToken);

                GetOtp();
            }
        });*/
    }
    public void sendOtp(View view)
    {
        SharedPreferences pref1= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(OtpActivity.this);
        String number=pref1.getString("contact",null);

        //verifyContact.setText(number);

        ccpVer.registerCarrierNumberEditText(contactVer.getEditText());
        String verCont=ccpVer.getFullNumberWithPlus();

        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(verCont,120, TimeUnit.SECONDS,OtpActivity.this,mCallbacks,forceResendingToken);
    }
    //auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks=new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                String code=phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
                otpAppear.setText(code);
                if(otpAppear!=null)
                {
                    //otpAppear.setText(code);
                    Toast.makeText(OtpActivity.this, "Contact Verified !!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(OtpActivity.this, "Contact Couldn't Be Verified !!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            Toast.makeText(OtpActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
            mVerificationId = s;
            PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token=forceResendingToken;
            Toast.makeText(OtpActivity.this, "Code Sent !!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
    /*private void GetOtp()
    {
        auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mCallbacks=new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                String code=phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
                if(code!=null)
                {
                    otpAppear.setText(code);
                    Toast.makeText(OtpActivity.this, "Contact Verified !!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(OtpActivity.this, "Contact Couldn't Be Verified !!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                Toast.makeText(OtpActivity.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);

                mVerificationId = s;
                PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token=forceResendingToken;
                Toast.makeText(OtpActivity.this,"Code sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };

    }*/
}
```

I am putting the sendOtp method in the onClick of the getOtp button. And when I am clicking the button it shows the Toast message "Contact Verified !!!" without even sending an OTP. Please help me with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
public class PHONE_ACTIVITY extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "PhoneAuthActivity";

private static final String KEY_VERIFY_IN_PROGRESS = "key_verify_in_progress";

private static final int STATE_INITIALIZED = 1;
private static final int STATE_CODE_SENT = 2;
private static final int STATE_VERIFY_FAILED = 3;
private static final int STATE_VERIFY_SUCCESS = 4;
private static final int STATE_SIGNIN_FAILED = 5;
private static final int STATE_SIGNIN_SUCCESS = 6;
@BindView(R.id.fieldPhoneNumber)
EditText fieldPhoneNumber;
@BindView(R.id.fieldVerificationCode)
EditText fieldVerificationCode;
@BindView(R.id.buttonStartVerification)
Button buttonStartVerification;
@BindView(R.id.buttonVerifyPhone)
Button buttonVerifyPhone;
@BindView(R.id.buttonResend)
Button buttonResend;
@BindView(R.id.phone_result)
TextView phoneResult;
@BindView(R.id.phone_email)
TextView phoneEmail;
@BindView(R.id.phone_phone)
TextView phonePhone;
@BindView(R.id.phone_name)
TextView phoneName;
@BindView(R.id.phone_image)
ImageView phoneImage;

// [START declare_auth]
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
// [END declare_auth]

private boolean mVerificationInProgress = false;
private String mVerificationId;
private PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;
private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone__activity);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    // Restore instance state
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    // [START initialize_auth]
    // Initialize Firebase Auth
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    // [END initialize_auth]

    // Initialize phone auth callbacks
    // [START phone_auth_callbacks]
    mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
            // This callback will be invoked in two situations:
            // 1 - Instant verification. In some cases the phone number can be instantly
            //     verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
            // 2 - Auto-retrieval. On some devices Google Play services can automatically
            //     detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verification without
            //     user action.
            Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted:" + credential);
            // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
            mVerificationInProgress = false;
            // [END_EXCLUDE]

            // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
            // Update the UI and attempt sign in with the phone credential
            updateUI(STATE_VERIFY_SUCCESS, credential);
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            // This callback is invoked in an invalid request for verification is made,
            // for instance if the the phone number format is not valid.
            Log.w(TAG, "onVerificationFailed", e);
            // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
            mVerificationInProgress = false;
            // [END_EXCLUDE]

            if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                // Invalid request
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                phoneResult.setError("Invalid phone number.");
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                /*Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Quota exceeded.",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                phoneResult.setError("Quota exceeded.");
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }

            // Show a message and update the UI
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            updateUI(STATE_VERIFY_FAILED);
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                               PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
            // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
            // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
            // by combining the code with a verification ID.
            Log.d(TAG, "onCodeSent:" + verificationId);

            // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
            mVerificationId = verificationId;
            mResendToken = token;

            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            // Update UI
            updateUI(STATE_CODE_SENT);
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
    };
    // [END phone_auth_callbacks]
}

@OnClick({R.id.buttonStartVerification, R.id.buttonVerifyPhone, R.id.buttonResend})
public void onViewClicked(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonStartVerification:

            if (!validatePhoneNumber()) {
                Toast.makeText(PHONE_ACTIVITY.this, "PHONE NUMBER NOT VALIDATE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                /*Log.d(TAG,"PHONE NUMBER NOT VALIDATE");*/
                return;
            }

            startPhoneNumberVerification(fieldPhoneNumber.getText().toString());
            break;
        case R.id.buttonVerifyPhone:
            String code = fieldVerificationCode.getText().toString();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(code)) {
                fieldVerificationCode.setError("Cannot be empty.");
                return;
            }

            verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(mVerificationId, code);
            break;
        case R.id.buttonResend:
            resendVerificationCode(fieldPhoneNumber.getText().toString(), mResendToken);
            break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(KEY_VERIFY_IN_PROGRESS, mVerificationInProgress);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    mVerificationInProgress = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_VERIFY_IN_PROGRESS);
}

private void startPhoneNumberVerification(String phoneNumber) {
    // [START start_phone_auth]
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
    // [END start_phone_auth]

    mVerificationInProgress = true;
}

private void verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(String verificationId, String code) {
    // [START verify_with_code]
    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
    // [END verify_with_code]
    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
}

// [START resend_verification]
private void resendVerificationCode(String phoneNumber,
                                    PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            mCallbacks,         // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
            token);             // ForceResendingToken from callbacks
}
// [END resend_verification]

// [START sign_in_with_phone]
private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");

                        FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        updateUI(STATE_SIGNIN_SUCCESS, user);
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    } else {
                        // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            // The verification code entered was invalid
                            // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
                            phoneResult.setError("Invalid code.");
                            // [END_EXCLUDE]
                        }
                        // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
                        // Update UI
                        updateUI(STATE_SIGNIN_FAILED);
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                }
            });
}
// [END sign_in_with_phone]

private void signOut() {
    mAuth.signOut();
    updateUI(STATE_INITIALIZED);
}

private void updateUI(int uiState) {
    updateUI(uiState, mAuth.getCurrentUser(), null);
}

private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
    if (user != null) {
        updateUI(STATE_SIGNIN_SUCCESS, user);
    } else {
        updateUI(STATE_INITIALIZED);
    }
}

private void updateUI(int uiState, FirebaseUser user) {
    updateUI(uiState, user, null);
}

private void updateUI(int uiState, PhoneAuthCredential cred) {
    updateUI(uiState, null, cred);
}

private void updateUI(int uiState, FirebaseUser user, PhoneAuthCredential cred) {
    switch (uiState) {
        case STATE_INITIALIZED:
            // Initialized state, show only the phone number field and start button
            enableViews(buttonStartVerification, fieldPhoneNumber);
            disableViews(buttonVerifyPhone, buttonResend, fieldVerificationCode);
            //mDetailText.setText(null);
            break;
        case STATE_CODE_SENT:
            // Code sent state, show the verification field, the
            enableViews(buttonVerifyPhone, buttonResend, fieldPhoneNumber, fieldVerificationCode);
            disableViews(buttonStartVerification);
            phoneResult.setText("CODE SENT");
            break;
        case STATE_VERIFY_FAILED:
            // Verification has failed, show all options
            enableViews(buttonStartVerification, buttonVerifyPhone, buttonResend, fieldPhoneNumber,
                    fieldVerificationCode);
            phoneResult.setText("VERIFICATION FAILED");
            break;
        case STATE_VERIFY_SUCCESS:
            // Verification has succeeded, proceed to firebase sign in
            disableViews(buttonStartVerification, buttonVerifyPhone, buttonResend, fieldPhoneNumber,
                    fieldVerificationCode);
            phoneResult.setText("succeeded");

            // Set the verification text based on the credential
            if (cred != null) {
                if (cred.getSmsCode() != null) {
                    fieldVerificationCode.setText(cred.getSmsCode());
                } else {
                    fieldVerificationCode.setText("ok");
                }
            }

            break;
        case STATE_SIGNIN_FAILED:
            // No-op, handled by sign-in check
            phoneResult.setText("SIGN IN FAILED");
            break;
        case STATE_SIGNIN_SUCCESS:
            // Np-op, handled by sign-in check
            break;
    }

    if (user == null) {
    } else {
        // Signed in
        //phoneResult.setText(user.getPhoneNumber());
        phoneEmail.setText(user.getEmail());
        phoneName.setText(user.getDisplayName());
        phonePhone.setText(user.getPhoneNumber());
        GlideApp.with(PHONE_ACTIVITY.this)
                .load(user.getPhotoUrl())
                .into(phoneImage);

    }
}

private boolean validatePhoneNumber() {
    String phoneNumber = fieldPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNumber)) {
        phoneResult.setError("Invalid phone number.");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private void enableViews(View... views) {
    for (View v : views) {
        v.setEnabled(true);
    }
}

private void disableViews(View... views) {
    for (View v : views) {
        v.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: But I don't want to sign in the user. I only want them to verify their contact numbers. So can this be done? Also can you suggest any modification that I can do in my code because I don't just want to copy your code. I also want to learn from the mistakes I make. So if you could point out any mistakes that I have made and also suggest some solution then I would be very grateful.

Comment: if you get the token after sign in then your number is verified. Another point, Your point is not clear and wrong so i could not modify your code. If you clean your code then i might try

Comment: You mean if I delete my code from my question then you might try right?